# Ленин и Ленский

Tags: имена-собственные

Ленин и Ленский. Интересно, псевдоним нашего вождя и фамилия пушкинского героя имеют общее происхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Небольшое дополнение. С Лениным все более или менее понятно. Что касается Владимира Ленского, то мы, действительно, ничего не знаем ни о прототипе, ни о мотивах, которыми руководствовался Пушкин, давая своему герою такую фамилию. Можно лишь отметить, что Ленский - поэт-романтик. Романтические герои ну просто не могут носить какую-нибудь заурядную фамилию. Фамилия Ленский очень подходит для данного персонажа, поскольку является относительно редкой. Далее привожу сведения о фамилии *Ленский* с сайта www.onomastikon.ru:

Фамилия **Ленский** в большинстве случаев имеет польское происхождение и формируется либо из самой Польши, либо из соседних с ней государств (Белоруссия, Украина). Подавляющее большинство представителей фамилии Ленский относились к польской шляхте. В 10% процентах носитель фамилии возможно является потомком древнего русского княжеского или боярского рода. Но в обоих случаях фамилия указывает, в основном, на местность, где проживали дальние предки человека или населенный пункт, откуда, по легендам, происходит этот род, однако фамилия может происходить и от имени или прозвища далекого предка человека. В 29% случаев эта фамилия принадлежала предку-священнослужителю. В таких случаях фамилия выпускнику духовной семинарии давалась по воле руководства училища и могла быть образована от названия местности, церковного праздника, имени святого.
 *Фамилия Ленский числится довольно малораспространенной на территориях России и соседних стран*. В некоторых ретроспективных дневниках обладатели этой фамилии были известными деятелями из славянского муромского купечества в XV-XVI в., имевшими значительную царскую привилегию. Первые свидетельства фамилии можно обнаружить в указателе переписи населения Руси в период царствования Иоанна Грозного. У правителя хранился особенный список привилегированных и приятнозвучащих фамилий, которые вручались придворным в случае особого расположения или награды.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку происхождение фамилиии персонажа достоверно известно только самому Пушкину, а происхождение псевдонима вождя достоверно вообще никому, то и разговор бессмысленный.

Пушкин скорее всего взял известную ему фамилию (он вообще никогда фамилии героев не изобретал, пользовался подсмотренным и подслушанным), поэтому для желаемого анализа пришлось бы искать происхождение фамилии неизвестного носителя.

Некоторая возможность для анализа оставалась бы в том случае, если Ленин придумал себе псевдоним не без помощи Пушкина, но подобное не находит ни малейшего подтверждения.

Вообще есть две версии происхождения псевдонима: официальная, от реки Лена, и более правдоподобная, связанная с существованием реального носителя фамилии. Подробности [здесь](http://100-000-pochemu.info/id/754).